# El programa se cierra al momento de dar click en el botón Graficar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, matplotlib

estoy desarrollando una gui donde pueda visualizar el funcinamiento de un piston en función de la frecuencia. Sin embargo, cuando le doy click al botón de Graficar, este se cierra. Ya revise las operaciones durante el proceso de graficar pero no presenta ningun error.

Este es el codigo.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDoubleValidator
from PyQt5.QtCore import QLocale
import math
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

#Clase Heredada de QMainWindow (Constructor de ventana)
class Ventana(QMainWindow):
      #Metodo constructor de la clase
      def __init__(self):
            #Iniciar el objeto QMainWindow
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            #Cargar la Configuracion del archivo ui en el objeto
            uic.loadUi("piston.ui",self)
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Guardar)
            #Convierte los valores en float 
            self._float_validator = QDoubleValidator()
            self.lineEdit.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            self.lineEdit_2.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            self.lineEdit_3.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            self.lineEdit_4.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            self.lineEdit_5.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            #Pone los lineEdit en 0 predeterminado
            self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_5.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self._locale = QLocale()
            #Declaracion de Widget para grafica
            self.figure = Figure()
            self.canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.figure)
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2QT(self.canvas, self.widget)
            self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
            self.plot_layout = QVBoxLayout()
            self.plot_layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
            self.plot_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
            self.widget.setLayout(self.plot_layout)


      def closeEvent(self,event):
            resultado = QMessageBox.question(self,"Salir..","¿Seguro quiere salir?",QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
            if resultado == QMessageBox.Yes:
                  event.accept()
            else:
                  event.ignore()

      def Guardar(self):
            rho, _ =self._locate.toDouble(self.lineEdit.text())
            c, _ =self._locate.toDouble(self.lineEdit_2.text())
            uo, _ =self._locate.toDouble(self.lineEdit_3.text())
            a, _ =self._locate.toDouble(self.lineEdit_4.text())
            fr, _ =self._locate.toDouble(self.lineEdit_5.text())
            fs = np.array((20,31.2, 63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 20000))
            ks = (2 * np.pi * fs) / c
            lamda=c/fr
            r=a((a/lamda)-((1/4)*(lamda/a)))
            p=np.array((2*rho*c*uo*(math.sin((1/4)*ks*r*((a/r)**2)))))

            self.axes.clear()
            self.axes.plot(fs, p,'b')
            self.axes.set_xscale('log')
            self.axes.set_title("Piston")
            self.axes.grid(True)
            self.canvas.draw()

#Instancia para iniciar una app
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#Crear un objeto de la clase
_ventana = Ventana()
#Mostrar ventana
_ventana.show()
#Ejecutar app
app.exec_()
```

Ya revise los parentesis y tampoco es problema, no estoy seguro si es un problema al momento de operar las variables o si son las variables de entrada que no las registra. Sin embargo, cuando le doy click al botón de Graficar, este se cierra. Ya revise las operaciones durante el proceso de graficar pero no presenta ningun error.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(972, 437)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 60, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 90, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 120, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 150, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 91, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 131, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 120, 141, 21))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 150, 91, 21))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 180, 211, 21))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 180, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 260, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 60, 481, 301))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 10, 301, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(25)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 972, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Rho"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Velocidad del sonido"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Velocidad Volumetrica"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Radio del piston"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Frecuencia de radiaicion del piston"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Graficar"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Piston Exponencial"))
```

Este es el codigo que exporte desde la consola para convertir el archivo piston.ui, que diseñe directamente en Qt Designer con el comando pyiu5 piston.ui -> piston.py

Gracias por la atención.

Comment: Por favor, publique el módulo `piston.ui`

Comment: Uff perdón se me olvido subirlo jajajaja, claro aquí esta el código ya edite la pregunta. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: `rho, _ =self._locate.toDouble(self.lineEdit.text())` ---> `AttributeError: 'Ventana' object has no attribute '_locate'`